# How to format properly a Java LocalDateTime for JSON (Javascript) using a DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, scala, java-time

I need to format a Java `java.time.LocalDateTime` into a JSON string that will match this format:

`2023-09-17T00:00:00.000+00:00`

I was looking at `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` defining my LocalDateTime with:

```scala
date.plusDays(daysToAdd)
   .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```

but that produces:

`2023-09-17T00:00:00Z`

Is there a predefined formatter for this date format? Do I need to create a custom DateTimeFormatter, if so could you provide an example for this format?

#### EDIT

I ended up using a formatter based on Mark Rotteveel's example solution and the subsequent comments to this question:

```scala
val jsonDateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")
    .toFormatter()
```

Comment: What is the problem with `2023-09-17T00:00:00Z`? It is the accepted rendering for offset 00:00 and supported by most parsers. In any case, if you really need +00:00, you'll need to create a custom pattern using `xxx` for the offset, see also the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) documentation.

Comment: I need to replicate the exact format of DateTime. I see that I can also use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html), but I was wondering if there was a predefined format for this specific one. I was looking for a possible example solution to add `.000+00:00`.

Comment: The solution you edited in (which BTW, you shouldn't normally do in questions) will not work correctly if you have non-zero fractional seconds (MILLI_OF_SECOND values). See also the comment on my answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @OleV.V. Patched with your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard formatter that gives the exact result you want. The use of `Z` for offset 0 is standard (probably derives from ISO 8601, but I'm too lazy to verify).

For the format you want, you'll need to build it up (see first example), or use a pattern (see second example). My example is in Java, but I assume it will translate directly to Scala:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var date = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-09-17T00:00:00");

    var fm = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .appendFraction(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)
            .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")
            .toFormatter();

    System.out.println(date.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(fm));
}
```

The most important parts here for your requirements are:

- `.appendFraction(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)`

  Ensures the fractional seconds are rendered in 3 digits.
- `.appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")`

  Renders the offset as `{+/-}HH:mm` (e.g. `-01:00`), and offset 0 as `+00:00`.

Output:

```
2023-09-17T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

You can also use a pattern-based formatter:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")
```

The use of `.SSS` ensures three fractional digits, and `xxx` renders the offset as `{+/-}HH:mm` and offset 0 as `+00:00`.

Note that it is probably best to use either of these formatters for formatting dates only, and use `ISO_DATE_TIME` for parsing, as it is more flexible and lenient.

Comment: (note: an earlier version of this answer used `ISO_DATE` instead of `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, and that produces a wrong result)

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to make it work for my needs using:

`val jsonDateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3, 3, true)
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")
    .toFormatter()`

Comment: I'm also using `ISO_DATE_TIME` for parsing because during testing, as you have already anticipated,  I experienced parsing errors in some edge cases.

Comment: Good point about using `+HH:MM` (vs `+HH:mm`). However, appending `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` and then using `appendFraction` will not work correctly (as `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` also appends fraction). For example, if you have a date with 120 milliseconds as fractional seconds, you'll end up with `2023-09-17T00:00:00.12.120+00:00` (note the `.12.120`).

Comment: @sentenza In any case, using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")` instead of the builder might be simpler.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help Mark. I will try with the simpler version using `DateTimeFormatter`.